# Are Hardy-Weinberg equilibrium assessment for two alleles on one loci or two locus?

Tags: genetics, hardy-weinberg

Are Hardy-Weinberg equilibrium assessment for two alleles on one loci or two locus? For instance, when the video says BB Bb bb https://www.khanacademy.org/science/ap-biology/natural-selection/hardy-weinberg-equilibrium/v/allele-frequency is it referring to two alleles, one of A/T/C/G on a position of a chromosome inherited from father and another from mother, or is it referring to two locus, one is one of {A,T,C,G} x {A,T,C,G} the other is one of {A,T,C,G} x {A,T,C,G}, choosing one of the  one from father and one from mother.

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology! feel free to take the [tour](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) etc. to learn more about the community. Usually we ask for some evidence of prior research via e.g. google or wiki before we answer stuff here. For example, there is a helpful [explainer from nature](https://www.nature.com/scitable/knowledge/library/the-hardy-weinberg-principle-13235724/) that talks about HW in some detail. If that doesn't answer your question, feel free to come back and update the Q with what's confusing.